# Enter array values into different rows of a column in ADF Dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to split the words of each row and insert each word I have split into the row and add them as a value. To do this I have split it and now in each row of the column I have an array and I have to insert each value of the array into the column as a different value.for example

with out separation:
columnWord
row1 white house
row2 blue sky

with split
columnword
row1[white house]
row2 [blue sky]

and i need
columnword
row1 white
row2 house
row3 blue
row4 sky

I have done the split and tried to add it to the column with an aggregate but I don't know which transformation to use.

Comment: Does your input and output look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/H9wESqo.png)

Answer (score 0):

To split the values in the `columnWord` column into separate rows, you can use the `split` function to split the string into an array of strings basis the space character`' '`, and then use the `unfold` function to expand the resulting array into separate rows. Here's an example of how to do this in an ADF Data Flow:

- Take the source transformation with the source dataset.

[image]
img:1 source data

- Then take the derived column and give the expression as
  `unfold(split(columnWord, ' '))`

[image]

img:2 derived column settings

**Output:**

[image]

img:3 data preview of derived column transformation